# Ajax comment system, JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new and I've been playing around with http://www.webcodo.net/comments-system-using-php-ajax/
I added up some function for pagination, but somehow the JS doesn't work after that

index.php

```
<?php
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

$per_page = 3; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

$statement = "`comments` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

$results = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

    // displaying records.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
?>
<div class="cmt-cnt">
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <?php echo $row['comment']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->

    <?php } } ?>

    <div class="new-com-bt">
        <span>Write a comment ...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="new-com-cnt">
        <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
        <input type="text" id="mail-com" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail adress" />
        <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
        <div class="bt-add-com">Post comment</div>
        <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

      <!--   echo $row['name'] . '<br>'; -->
</div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->

<?php // displaying paginaiton.
echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?');
// var_dump($pagination);
?>

</body>

<!-- JS script -->
<?php include_once('script.js'); ?>

</html>
```

This is the javascript code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(function(){ 
    //alert(event.timeStamp);
    $('.new-com-bt').click(function(event){    
        $(this).hide();
        $('.new-com-cnt').show();
        $('#name-com').focus();
    });

    /* when start writing the comment activate the "add" button */
    $('.the-new-com').bind('input propertychange', function() {
       $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:0.6});
       var checklength = $(this).val().length;
       if(checklength){ $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:1}); }
    });

    /* on clic  on the cancel button */
    $('.bt-cancel-com').click(function(){
        $('.the-new-com').val('');
        $('.new-com-cnt').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('.new-com-bt').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });

    // on post comment click 
    $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
        var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
        var theName = $('#name-com');
        var theMail = $('#mail-com');

        if( !theCom.val()){ 
            alert('You need to write a comment!'); 
        }else{ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                data: 'act=add-com&id_post=+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
                success: function(html){
                    theCom.val('');
                    theMail.val('');
                    theName.val('');
                    $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                        $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                        $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                    })
                }  
            });
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: *Somehow doesn't work*?

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML, give us a link to the output page, or tell us what error or symptoms you're experiencing.

Comment: so the JS is not working, when I clicked the on the new comment ( class = "new-com-bt" ). it should show input form for new comment, name and email.